# Allocating space to Ubuntu from Windows

Tags: partitioning

I've got Ubuntu, Windows and some unallocated space on my computer. Can I allocate that space to Ubuntu from Windows? If not, is it possible without livecd?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, Windows can't create Linux-format partitions.

If it's unallocated, you can allocate and format it from Ubuntu. If it's currently formatted as something else that you want to repurpose, you may be able to unmount it while in Ubuntu and free it up.

But if all else fails, the LiveCD will let you do anything because nothing on the disk will be mounted by default.

Comment: So, if I format it, can I add it directly from Ubuntu?

Comment: I think so, yeah.